# JQuery validator - how to force it to show additional errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, unobtrusive-validation

On ajax form postback I receive JSON-ed server-side validation errors (Something like this: "Input.Name: {Errors}"), so I wonder if I can do something like this:

```
$.validator. ... ( json );
$("form").validate();
```

So the form gets validated once again, but showing new errors from the server response (showing field errors and doing errored field highlighting).

By far I found a lot of solutions that suggest doing it manually, i.e. adding error elements/classes and other jobs jquery validator does. I would prefer doing it simple and reuse jquery validator functionality, but I still can't find how. Is it posssible? I would appreciate any directions.

**Edit:** Temporarily I simply alert all the errors. Ideally, I would like to leave this code as simple as possible.

```
if (response && response.Tag && response.Tag == "Success") {
     window.location = response.State;
 }

 if (response && response.Tag && response.Tag == "ValidationError") {
     $.each(response.State, function (i, item) {
         alert(item.Errors.join("; "));
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jQuery validate if you're willing to break down validation of every field into another ajax service - a validation service per field. If the request results with true, the field is presumed to be valid, and when the request results with some string, this string is presumed to be an error message. Look at the code below (it's taken from the [validate remote method documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/)):

```js
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: {
        url: "check-email.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
          username: function() {
            return $( "#username" ).val();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: In my case I send ajax postback once, and get errors for each field from the server (Something like this: "Input.Name: {Errors}"). Yhe problem is to somehow tell jquery validator to accept this response as a new rule.

Comment: You could either extend validate service (which will be hard) or just break down your validation service. You don't even have to have multiple validation endpoints - you can just have one with parameters like this: `/validate/email`, `/validate/phoneNumber` which will all be handled by one controller.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but I'm not sure if I can easily apply this approach into my ASP.MVC application logic (Where controller rather accept and process data from the entire form). Besides, what if validation of one field depends on validation of the previous one?

Comment: When validator posts data to server to check if it's valid it posts just one this field in the POST request data, so you could structure this somehow. Of course if validation of one field depends on another this complicates a lot... What you can do then is specify errorContainer for validation errors, and when you submit form the usual way and get in response JSON object with errors you can add those errors to the errorContainer so that they look the same as the rest. But I don't see an easy way to process such server errors and show them by the fields.

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid doing validator job manually, such as dealing with error-containers and field-highlighting (although, didn't find any other solution). Maybe, it is really the only dirty way to do this, but I'll dig a little bit more to know for sure.